# List only numeric file names in directory

Tags: linux, bash

I have a list of files with numeric file names (e.g. #.php, ##.php or ###.php) that I'd like to copy/move in one fell swoop.

Does anyone know of an `ls` or `grep` combo command to accomplish this objective?

I do have this much:

```
ls -al | grep "[0-9].php"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use regular expression when listing files:

```
ls [0-9]*
```

This was an easy and minimalistic approach at the above problem but I think a better solution is

```
ls -al | grep -E '^[0-9]+\.php$'
```

as UncleZeiv explains [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151338/list-only-numeric-file-names-in-directory/3151391#3151391).

Comment: Surely this depends on the shell? For example `bash` wouldn't treat that as a regular expression. Try it and you'll see it matches _any_ file whose name starts with a number.

Comment: Actually I'm running bash and it worked perfectly.  This was far too simple.  Thanks for the solution.  I used cp [0-9]*

Comment: @gurun8: You were lucky you didn't have any files with non-numeric characters in their name then.

Comment: @gurun8 may be this worked for you, but this would fail if there are files such as 123myfile.php

Comment: This works only by accident and shouldn't be the accepted answer. Try it with a directory that contains a file such as `0a.txt`.

Comment: That's globbing, not a regular expression.

Answer (score 8):

In Bash, you can use extended pattern matching:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls -l +([0-9]).php
```

which will find files such as:

```
123.php
9.php
```

but not

```
a.php
2b.php
c3.php
```

Answer (score 7):

Amend it like this:

```
ls -al | grep -E '^[0-9]+\.php$'
```

`-E` activates the extended regular expressions.

`+` requires that at least one occurrence of the preceding group must appear.

`\.` escape dot otherwise it means "any character."

`^` and `$` to match the entire filename and not only a part.

Single quotes to prevent variable expansion (it would complain because of the `$`).

Comment: Don't use `ls` in scripts, it is intended only for interactive use.

Comment: @Philipp: Nobody mentioned scripts.

Comment: @Troubadour: The pipe into `grep` makes it a "script".

Comment: @Troubadour: You're right, but I don't think that the OP asks a question like this for interactive use. Also, many people who do write scripts read these posts.

Comment: @Philipp: Nothing about the question even hints at non-interactive use so that's a real jump. Also, you can't turn the question into a scripting question just because you think people who write scripts might be reading.

Comment: Edit to first comment: "Don't use `ls` in scripts or pipes, it is intended only for interactive use. See [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)."

Comment: @Philipp, @Dennis: ok, ok, no more `ls` in scripts or pipes, I promise!

Answer (score 4):

Use find:

```
$ find . -regex '^[0-9]+\.php' -exec mv '{}' dest/ ';'
```

Note that the `-regex` argument does a search, not a match, which is why the ^ is there to anchor it to the start. This also assumes that the files are in the same directory (.) as the one you're in when running the command.

The `{}` trickery in the `mv` command is replaced by `find` with the found filename.

Comment: but no +1 for using it this way. This will break on file names with spaces or newlines. Instead use `find . -regex '^[0-9]+\.php' -exec mv '{}' dest/ ';'`, or `xargs -0`.

Comment: @Philipp: Thanks, that's more robust. I got the impression the original poster's set of filenames didn't contain spaces, but being safe is better of course.

Comment: If the pattern is really just `^[0-9]+\.php$`, then of course your original code doesn't cause problems. However, I guess that lots of readers would blindly modify your code to include other patterns which then lead to problems.

Answer (score 2):

Either use `find` (possibly combined with the `-XXXdepth` options):

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -regex '^[0-9]+\.php' -exec mv '{}' dest/ ';'
```

Or use the builtin regex capabilities:

```
pattern='^[0-9]+\.php$'
for file in *.php
do
    [[ $file =~ $pattern ]] && echo "$file"
done
```

Don't use `ls` or `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

This below worked in my case:

```
ls -an
```